# Isolate coil from battery using two transistors triggered by Hall sensor

Tags: transistors, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, hall-effect

My current, simplified pulsed electric motor driver circuit is shown in the image below on the left.

[image]

The base of the PNP transistor is connected to a A3144E Hall sensor, and this pulses the coil when the rotor magnet passes by the drive coil shown in the circuit.

The incoming rotor magnet also induces a counter EMF in the coil (per Lenz and Faraday), which will create a load on the battery.

This load I want to block by isolating the coil from the battery using a second transistor above the drive coil, *until* we initiate the pulse.

I tried the circuit on the right, where two PNP transistors are driven from the same Hall sensor signal, but in the simulation this seemed to greatly diminish the power flowing through the coil.

**How can I correctly trigger two transistors, one on each end of a coil, from the same Hall sensor signal?**

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Since some commenters seem to suggest that the single PNP transistor does not work, here is the proof that it actually works very well:

https://youtu.be/X33VJsSbThQ

Also, here is (part of) a circuit someone uses to do exactly what I am trying to do (isolate the coil from the circuit) using two MOSFETS:

[image]

I don't fully understand the exact way in which it works, and he seems to use a low side P-channel FET switch.

The difference is that his Hall signal is inverted and so HIGH when a magnet passes.

Comment: Why did you assume PNP was the way to go?  Then when it failed, why did you think 2 would be better?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 ... two wrongs make a right? ... lol

Comment: use a low side Nch  FET Switch with fly back diode rated for >5x motor rating current

Comment: The single PNP actually works very well, as the Hall sensor goes LOW when a magnet is close by. That's why I thought I could place the same one before the coil as well. The N-FET you mention should be placed before AND after the coil?

Comment: You only need to break a circuit in one place to make it no longer a circuit.  N channel devices perform better than P channel ones, so typically you'd use a *single* N-FET as a low side switch.  Then put a reversed diode across the coil alone.

Comment: In your first schematic on the left the transistor (see why we label diagrams and apply component designators?) you have a PNP in the negative supply to the coil. You have to pull the base below 0 V  to get it to turn on. Your video proves nothing. There is no circuit schematic shown in it. There seems to be some suggestion that the thing can run off one battery and charge another so it sounds like a perpetual motion machine or free energy system (which is impossible).

Comment: Chris Stratton thanks for your reply! But isn't it then an emitter-follower? I built those before and I was told to place the transistor AFTER the load @Transistor There's no "perpetual motion", nothing crazy is going on. I simply use a flyback diode across the coil and place a capacitor or battery there, which then collects the flyback EMF from the collapsing magnetic field. Try it, it works.

Comment: The circuit in the video is exactly this: https://images.app.goo.gl/U8npTtAfKMmdGXQF7 The flyback diode etc I added in later tests.